# Prove the equivalence of the modified Turing Machines and the standard Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, automata, simulation

We have a Turing Machine that cannot write the same symbol it has read in a transition, meaning it should always alter the symbol when passing it. How can we prove that such machines have equal processing power compared with the standard Turing Machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a modified Turing machine is a special kind of the standard Turing machine, the power of modified Turing machines is at most that of standard Turing machines.

Now suppose $S$ is a stand Turing machine with $\Gamma$ as its alphabet on tape.

Let $\Gamma'$ be a copy of $\Gamma$, i.e., for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$, there is a corresponding $\gamma'\in\Gamma'$.

Let Turing machine $M$ be the same as $S$ except that

- $M$'s alphabet on tape is $\Gamma\sqcup\Gamma'$.
- Suppose $M$ read $\alpha\in\Gamma$ or $\alpha'\in \Gamma'$. Then $M$ will behave like $S$ as if $S$ had read $\alpha$, except that $M$ will write $\beta'$ instead if $S$ would write $\beta\in\Gamma$ when $\alpha$ was read.

We see that $M$ is a modified Turing machine that simulates $S$. Hence the power of modified Turing machines is at least that of standard Turing machines.